# How to move the directory to the remote using rsync?

Tags: javascript, rsync

It was bit confusing how to ask this question.
I have a folder named as `exec`, inside `exec` folder I have files as

```
node_modules

exec.js

hello.txt  

package.json
```

**AIM**: I want to move this folder `exec` to my remote machine using rsync.

In `exec.js` I wrote the logic in order to move the folder to my remote,(before 
that I checked whether rsync is working by taking a dummy txt file and made it to move to remote machine which was achieveable for me).

**exec.js**

```
   console.log('1');
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;


    exec('node -v'+ '&& dir'+ '&& rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\
 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress\
 hello.txt ec2-user@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/ec2-user/exec',\   //how to include the folder exec in place of hello.txt, so that my whole folder moves to remote?
 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout', stdout);
          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ', error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the way out of this question,

'*' will work in place of hello.txt.

```
 console.log('1');
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;


    exec('node -v'+ '&& dir'+ '&& rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no\
 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress\
 * ec2-user@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/ec2-user/exec',\   //how to include the folder exec in place of hello.txt, so that my whole folder moves to remote?
 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout', stdout);
          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ', error);
        }
    });
```